# closed and open elements in an array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements, nested-loops

I am writing a code to indicate open and closed elements in a 2d array. An open element is represented with `.` and a closed element is represented with `*`. The first column in the array must be completely open whereas all the other columns must be closed. The output should be:

```
.**
.**
.**
```

The array is also going to vary in size as the user will determine how big the array is. I have managed to code a 2D array grid as this is not hard, however, I am trying to now use an if-statement to make the first column all open. I placed the if-statement within the nested loop:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class trial {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What size square grid do you want? ");
    int m = sc.nextInt();
    char[][] grid = new char[m][m];
    int i;
    int j;
        for(i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<grid[i].length; j++) {
                grid[i][j] ='.';
                if(grid[j].length > grid[0].length) {
                    System.out.println("");
                }else {
                    System.out.print('*');
                }
                StdOut.print(grid[i][j]);
            }
            StdOut.println();
        }
        
}
```

}

This, however, is giving me an output that looks like this:

```
*.*.*.
*.*.*.
*.*.*.
*.*.*.
```

I have tried placing the if-statement outside of this nested for-loop but I then get an error with my variables as they have not been defined. Any assistance as to how to fix this or make it that I can get values for my `i` and `j` variables outside of the for-loop would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modify your code to make it fit the description.

`i` and `j` will vary when the loop proceeds, and should be accessed inside the loop only.

It seems that you want to change the content inside `grid`, which can be accessed outside the loop after processing.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What size square grid do you want? ");
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        char[][] grid = new char[m][m];
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = '.';
                if(j > 0) {
                    grid[i][j] = '*';
                }
                System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        // you cannot access i/j outside the loop scope. instead, you can access the grid
        System.out.println("Loaded array:");
        Arrays.stream(grid).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the current column is 0 or not
Just a minor change will work here
I am writing only the main loop below

```
for(i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {

    for(j=0; j<grid[i].length; j++) {
       if(j == 0){          //0th column make it dot(.)
          grid[i][j] ='.';
       }
       else {              //For other columns put asterisk(*)
         grid[i][j] = '*';
       }  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way to think about 2D arrays. They are simply a 1D array where each element is itself another 1D array (a complete "row").

With that in mind, here's a different way to initialize and print the contents of the 2D array using a mixture of [enhanced and indexed for loops](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-for-loop-and-enhanced-for-loop-in-java/):

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What size square grid do you want? ");
    int m = sc.nextInt();
    char[][] grid = new char[m][m];
    
    for(char[] row : grid) {
      for(int col=0; col<row.length; col++) {
        row[col] = (col == 0) ? '.' : '*';
      }
    }

    for(char[] row : grid) {
      for(char c : row) {
        System.out.print(c);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
What size square grid do you want? 
5
.****
.****
.****
.****
.****
```